# Stack Image/Icon Links on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like this:
[image: No hover]

When the user hovers over a specific campground, this happens

[image: hover]

**What I want to achieve:**

- When user clicks edit button (blue), go to edit page
- When user clicks delete, delete campground
- When user clicks anywhere else in the gray shaded area, he just goes to the campground show page (i.e a page with more info on that
  campground)

**My problem:** When the user clicks edit/delete, I'm just redirected to the campground show page

The Code:

```
<a href="/campgrounds/<%= ground._id %>/" class="imagePins">

    <div class="imgAndCap">
         <div class="imgbackground" style="background-image: url(//someurl');"></div>
         <div class="caption">
              <p> <%= groundname %></p>
         </div> <!-- caption end -->
    </div>

    <div class="overlay">
         <% var groundDelID = campgrounds[i].id + "groundDelete"; %>
         <i id="<%=groundDelID%>" class="fa fa-times groundDelete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <% var groundEditID = campgrounds[i].id + "groundEdit"; %>
         <i id="<%=groundEditID%>" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o groundEdit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <script> 
             $("#<%=groundEditID%>").on("click", function(e) { 
                   window.url("/campgrounds/<%= ground._id %>/edit");
             });
         </script>
     </div>
```

I tried doing something like

```
<a href=""/campgrounds/<%= ground._id %>/edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o groundEdit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

But this disabled the hover effect -- i.e, on hover the transparent black background didn't appear and neither did the icons

**CSS:** Not sure how relevant this is, but adding it anyway

```
.imagePins {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-decoration:  none;
    color: dimgray;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {     
   display: none;
}

.overlay i {
  float: right;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.groundDelete {
  color: #d9534f;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.groundEdit {
  color: #5bc0de ;
  margin-right: 0.7rem;
}

.imagePins:hover .overlay { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

So how do I stack links on top of each other?

Comment: `<a href=""/campgrounds/...` <-- Are you sure that typo (double apostrophe) isn't causing any issues? It also sounds like you need to create a stacking context by declaring `z-index` properties on your icons (I'm assuming they're already absolutely positioned judging by their placements in the screenshots provided)

Comment: No that was just a typo in stackoverflow. I tried the z-index trick, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You have whole item wrapped in `<a href="/campgrounds/<%= ground._id %>/" class="imagePins"></a>`, so you will be redirect on that link. You should make a wrapper and than add link into it.

```
<div class="imagePins>
  <a href="/campgrounds/<%= ground._id class="imagePins__link" %></a>

  ...

</div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.imagePins {
  position: relative;
  ...
}

.imagePins__link {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 50;
}

.groundDelete,
.groundEdit {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This worked. I used your code and then this <a href="/campgrounds/<%=ground.id%>/edit"><i id="<%=groundEditID%>" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o groundEdit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method for edit and delete events.